# The fundamental group of the complement of a curve.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $C$ is a homomorphism from the real numbers into $\mathbb{R^3}$, i.e. an open, regular curve. What's the fundamental group of the complement of $Im[C]$? If $Im[C]$ is a line the fundamental group is infinite cyclic because it deformation retracts onto a punctured plane and then onto a circle which have infinite cyclic fundamental group. I strongly believe that the complement of $Im[C]$ has infinite cyclic fundamental group even if $Im[C]$ is a general open curve (topologically embedded in space). After all a loop have to wind around the curve or otherwise be null-homotopic. But how to proof that? Of course $Im[C]$ is homeomorhic to a line so if I could extend this homeomorphism to the entire space its restriction to the complement would also be a homeomorphism with the image $\mathbb{R}^3-Im[C]$ and we are done. But does such an extension exist? Would it be easier to proof this for a specific curve, such as a parabola or a helix? If my conjecture turns out to be false after all, what conditions on C would guarantee it to be true?

A similar question is if we cut out a compact curve segment from the plane, $\mathbb{R^2}$, would the complement have infinite cyclic fundamental group? The curve segment is contractible but does that proof the claim?

Comment: The study of curve complements is known as knot theory. It is a deep subject and certainly cannot be concluded in a single math se post.

Comment: You should impose some conditions on the topological embedding $f: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}^3$ describing your curve $C$. The standard one is "properness" of the map $f$. In any case, the fundamental group of the complement can be quite complicated, say, non-finitely generated.

Comment: As the previous comments have stated, this is a big ask. But the "Wirtinger presentation" is a topic you might want to Google.

Comment: @ Charles Hudgins: Fair enough but I said that the curve is homeomorphic to a line, hence unknotted. Anyway it must be possible to say something about my specific examples: the parabola and the infinite curcular helix, two simple, unknotted curves.

Comment: Okay I made a mistake. I intend an unknotted curve but homeomorphic to line doesn't imply it. Excuse me but I'm a newbe to topology.

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan: Condition is that it shall be unknotted. I don't know what proper mean in this context. Also it should extend infinitely in both directions.

Comment: Proper pretty much takes care of the undefined terminology "extend infinitely in both directions." But what do you mean by "$C$ is unknotted"? The standard meaning is that there exists a homeomorphism $R^3\to R^3$ sending $C$ to a straight line. Is this what you mean? If so, you already solved your problem.